# How to write this associative query in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How to write this associative query in laravel 5.2 ?

relationships：

```
users and articles , one to many.
categories and articles , one to many.
```

query：
1、I want to get the current user's articles.
2、I want to get articles' category.

```
public function index()
{
    $user=\Auth::user();

    //I use this sentence to query：
    $articles = $user->articles->with('category');

    return view('index',  compact('articles'));
}
```

error：
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Please copy and paste all of stack trace here. Right now you are using an image to show its first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
$articles = $user->articles()->with('category')->get();
```